# Android Calculate percentage

Tags: java, android

I'm new to android and Java, and I have to design a simple application that reads an amount and shows a 10 percent of this amount in a toast. This is my code:

activity_main.xml:

```
 <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/amount"
        android:hint="Bill amount in L.L"
        android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:inputType="number"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="10%"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/amount"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
        android:onClick="tenp"/>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
 public void tenp(View view1) {

       EditText e = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.amount);


        double amount = Double.parseDouble(e.getText().toString());

        double res = (amount / 100.0f) * 10;

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" +res, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

When I run my app and click on the 10% button, the app closes. I don't know what is my error here. please help.

Comment: post your logcat errors

Comment: I don't know how to debug using android studio and bluestacks.

Comment: @user3640056 https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-studio.html refer this it help you how to debug

Comment: What do you mean by `click on the 10% button`?

Comment: you ahve implement setOnClickListener?...can you post more code? or logcat?

Comment: Your code is fine, Please enter value in the editext before you click the button.

Comment: I don't know what happened, but when I connected bluestacks to android studio it worked fine. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your code is fine except for the handling the invalid parsing of double.
You can modify your code for the invalid parsing of double as-

```
public void tenp(View view1) {

        EditText e = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.amount);
        if (!e.getText().toString().equals("")) {
            double amount = Double.parseDouble(e.getText().toString());
            double res = (amount / 100.0f) * 10;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + res, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Amount cannot be empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    }
```